# How to get human face feature's size in Python using face recognition?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, deep-learning, face-recognition

I have **face recognition** model in Python which detects face and differentiates the  features like *eyes, nose, mouth* from a face. I want to filter-out the face features (face parts) depending upon their sizes, so that I can easily get persons if they have big eyes or small eyes without displaying the whole data.

Can anyone suggest what should I use to detect facial feature's size?

Comment: The faces you are detecting will be in different distances to the camera so their pixel sizes will be different. You can use the ratio to decide whose eyes small or big

Comment: look at dlib's 68 facial landmarks. That might work.